# Google analytics, not enough events

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

The question might be common but didn't find it anywhere. 
I'm tracking events in google analytics via measurement protocol. On the analytics page I can create up to 20 events. Let's say I got an invoice and there are 20 sources from where it may come, I need to send that data to analytics, so let's say category invoice action pay and the label is bank transfer, cash etc. I heard label can be left empty on the analytics event manager page, and still if I fill the label in my code It will be shown. I hope I stated myself clear enough :)

Cheers!

Comment: I think you forgot the question part of your question want to try again?

Comment: Well maybe... Do i have to define labels on the analytics page? Or they can be made dynamically in the code?

Comment: Events arent like custom dimensions its just a string you send.  You can submit what ever you want.   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#events

Comment: Ahh okay thank you! Thought that those need to be pre-defined on the analytics page :) Thanks for help man! Have good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are not predefined its basically just text that you can add.  Things like custom dimensions need to be predefined.

You are also correct label is not required [events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#events)

Comment: To add to @DalmTo's answer: if you collect lots of events with lots of different values, you will run into cardinality issues and see `(other)` entries: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009671?hl=en. But we're talking thousands of different values, not 20 :)